# Is there a User/Owner concept in Hyperleder Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Quick question in Ethereum if you are engaging with a Smart Contract you can determine which address is interacting with the Smart Contracts and you can reject transaction if the address isn't on a white list. (I.E. this is the Ethereum concept of a user)

In Fabric Composer you can define participants and you can reject a transaction if the participant doesn't have permission to interact with the asset, method whatever. (The Participant acts as a user and has permission to interact with something)

In Hyperledger Fabric most of the example code doesn't include this concept. So for example the Marble_Chaincode anyone can change the ownership of the marble. Instead of the ownership of a marble being tied to a particular user.

Am I missing something or is there a way of determining which individual is pushing the transaction to the Blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you are seeing a simple sample of chaincode. Inside the chaincode you can access to the information of the user who is making the transaction. Check this links:

[Hyperledger Fabric CA - Client](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity)
[Hyperledger Fabric Nodejs Contract and Shim - Class Identity](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html#toc0__anchor)

So with this you can create new identities with fabric ca and check it inside the contract with fabric shim

Comment: Thank you, so to add to your answer...

In Ethereum the User is an Address.
In Fabric Composer the User is a Participant
In Fabric it's a Client.